# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<JobClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to perform a job after saving a record.

Here is my code:

`/app/models/some_todo_model.rb`

```rb
class SomeTodoModel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  after_save :create_job_for_notificate_on_due_date

  def create_job_for_notificate_on_due_date
    EmitsNotificationsJob.set(wait_until: self.due_date).perform_later()
  end
end
```

`/app/jobs/emits_notifications_job.rb`

```rb
class EmitsNotificationsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  # discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError

  def perform()
  end
end
```

`EmitsNotificationsJob.set(wait_until: self.due_date)` is setting it well.

But when I am calling `perform_later` I have the following error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for #<EmitsNotificationsJob:0x000056387e74ce78>`

[image]

I don't understand my issue since I am following the documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

As it might be for the same reason, if I am uncommenting the `discard_on` line, I am having the following error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'discard_on' for EmitsNotificationsJob:Class`

Comment: Please, provide actual and exact code of `app/jobs/emits_notifications_job.rb`.

Comment: This is the actual code of it, nothing more really.
Just having a `binding.pry` in the first line of my `perform` method (but never entering it).

Comment: Also tried to call `perform_later` with no parameter or a string instead of `self`, but nothing changed....

Comment: That is not actual code. Due to error, code has something like `def perform name`.

Comment: You have syntax error here. Use parentheses: `def perform(todo)`

Comment: Same with parenthesis...

Comment: Have you restarted your  active_job.queue_adapter after fix?

Comment: Using the default `async` as `active_job.queue_adapter` for now.
This is just a starting project (learning how to use Jobs).

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD** You have copied wrong example(missed `.class` after job):

```
class ApplicationJob
  before_enqueue { |job| $statsd.increment "#{job.class.name.underscore}.enqueue" }
end
```

Also, I strongly suggest to remove `before_enqueue` line from `app/jobs/application_job.rb` at all. It's just example of `before_enqueue` callback and the example looks like non-working.

Comment: "You have to use parentheses when define method with parameters" - in fact, no, they don't. I like parenthesized version better, but it's perfectly valid ruby as-is.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The first version of post was very different.

Comment: [def perform todo](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56079418/1), this version? That's valid ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yep. Without error screenshot, I thought his actual code is something like `def perform name end`. `ApplicationJob` was not provided either (and it is empty by default).

Comment: I don't see why you'd think that. Your suggestion about `class` looks spot-on, but these assertions about syntax error are plain wrong. I suggest you remove them (here and comments)

Comment: JFYI, no need to do the "UPD, UPD2" thing. This is not reddit, full revision history is available :) When deleting/adding stuff, simply do that (useful revision comment  won't hurt)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Old habits die hard.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk you were right about `before_enqueue` presence causing the issue.
Just copied the following without thinking...:  
[https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#callbacks]...

Comment: Still having the `discard_on` issue though ^^ .
I should probably re-post a question for this one.